Why the newly added data is not reflecting in the table component of primevue?
I am trying to create a Expense Tracker where a super user could create user accounts and its data is stored inside a pinia store. The table component should detect the change in the user account array and reflect the newly added user in this table.
I'm new to vue3 and pinia.
File: store.js


import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { computed, ref, reactive } from 'vue'

export const Store = defineStore('finance', () => {
  const getDate = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date()
    return currentDate.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      year: 'numeric',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      second: 'numeric'
    })
  }

  const superUser = { email: 'Christian@bank.com', secret: 'Munich' }

  let userIdCount = 1
  const userAccounts = ref([
    {
      accountID: userIdCount++,
      accountName: 'Veer',
      balance: 250,
      created: getDate(),
      updated: '-'
    }
  ])

  const savingsHistory = ref([])
  const expenseHistory = ref([])
  // const stateAccount = reactive({
  //   userAccount: [
  //     {
  //       accountID: userIdCount++,
  //       accountName: 'Veer',
  //       balance: 250,
  //       created: getDate(),
  //       updated: '-'
  //     }
  //   ],
  //   savingsHistory: [],
  //   expenseHistory: []
  // })

  const addUser = (name, initialBalance) => {
    const userDetail = {
      accountID: userIdCount++,
      accountName: name,
      balance: initialBalance,
      created: getDate(),
      updated: '-'
    }
    console.log(userDetail)

    userAccounts.value.push(userDetail)
    console.log(`Array after: ${userAccounts.value}`)
  }

  const updateSaving = (id, saving) => {
    const account = userAccounts.value.find((acc) => acc.accountID === id)
    if (account) {
      account.updated = getDate()
      account.balance += saving
      console.log(`Savings Before Update: ${savingsHistory.value}`)

      savingsHistory.value.push({
        user: account.accountName,
        savings: saving,
        updated: account.updated
      })
      console.log(`Savings Updated: ${savingsHistory.value}`)
    }
  }

  const updateExpense = (id, expense) => {
    const account = userAccounts.value.find((acc) => acc.accountID === id)
    if (account && account.balance >= expense) {
      account.updated = getDate()
      account.balance -= expense
      expenseHistory.value.push({
        user: account.accountName,
        expense: expense,
        updated: account.updated
      })
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  const state = reactive({
    showAccountFormStatus: false,
    showSavingsFormStatus: false,
    showExpenseFormStatus: false
  })

  const toggleAccountForm = () => (state.showAccountFormStatus = !state.showAccountFormStatus)
  const toggleSavingsForm = () => (state.showSavingsFormStatus = !state.showSavingsFormStatus)
  const toggleExpenseForm = () => (state.showExpenseFormStatus = !state.showExpenseFormStatus)

  const getFullName = computed(() => superUser.email.split('@')[0])
  const getUserAccounts = computed(() => [...userAccounts.value])

  return {
    superUser,
    getFullName,
    toggleAccountForm,
    toggleSavingsForm,
    toggleExpenseForm,
    addUser,
    state,
    userAccounts,
    savingsHistory,
    expenseHistory,
    updateSaving,
    updateExpense,
    getUserAccounts
  }
})



File: TableComponent.vue


<script setup>
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable'
import Column from 'primevue/column'
import { Store } from '@/stores/store'

import { computed, nextTick } from 'vue'

// Initialize the store
const store = Store()

// // Access the user accounts directly from stateAccount

// console.log(userAccounts)

const userAccounts = computed(() => store.getUserAccounts)

console.log(userAccounts.value)

nextTick(() => {
  console.log('User Accounts:', userAccounts.value)
})

// console.log(userAccounts)
</script>

<template>
  <DataTable :value="userAccounts" showGridlines responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <Column field="accountID" header="Account-ID"></Column>
    <Column field="accountName" header="Account User"></Column>
    <Column field="balance" header="Balance"></Column>
    <Column field="created" header="Created-On"></Column>
    <Column field="updated" header="Updated-On"></Column>
  </DataTable>
</template>



Why it is not working as expected?
Need some help with clear explanation.

please provide explanation for your code.  it is helpful to others if you can describe expected code flow.  if you have any debug details, provide them... you have console.logs.  are they executing?  are they showing correct values? where exactly do you see things start to go wrong?

In the store code, I am trying to save the user details in an Array in the form of objects {name, amount}. I am using this array to display the user details in the table component. I want to track the user array everytime for new values. When a user is added newly into the array, it should be reflected in the table as well.
I am using PrimeVue library to display the table. Here we should mention exactly the fields as in the object for it pick the data.

I don't think the syntax you are using works in pinia as you described, specially because pinia already has properties to handle mutation, and the declaration you are using is related to vanilla vue.
But related to your issue, what is happening is that, in your store you already have defined the getUserAccounts as  a computed property, and when you retrive it in your TableComponent.vue you are passing it again as a computed.
You need to follow this syntax in your files o get them working:
Store.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => ({
    // ...all mutable properties here
    counter: 0,
  }),
  getters: {
    // ... All getters properties here
    doubleCount: (state) => state.counter * 2,
  },
  actions: {
    increment() {
      this.counter++;
    },
  },
});

MockComponent.vue:
import { useCounterStore } from '../store/location';

const userStore = useCounterStore();

console.log(userStore.count)
userStore.count += 1
console.log(userStore.count)

console.log(userStore.doubleCount)
userStore.increment()
console.log(userStore.count)

Here are some core concepts of pinia that you should be aware when defining stores: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/
Feel free to reach me if you have any doubts.
